# Count of values from a different table in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a table A and B with 2 columns, as below. I wanted to display the count of count if values from Table with respect to a column in table A. My expected outcome display should be similar to Final Display.

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3OPC.png)]

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc772.png)]

outcome:

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3iIf.png)]

Thanks,

Gowtham

Answer (score 0):

Merge TableA into TableB

[image]

Expand the ID column then group on ID with rowcount

[image]

Table B Code:

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TableBSourceData"]}[Content],
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"SUBID"}, #"Table A", {"SUBID"}, "Table A", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table A" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table A", {"ID"}, {"ID"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Expanded Table A", {"ID"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in  #"Grouped Rows"
```